# How can i use 2 temperature sensors with raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, temperature

How can i use 2 temperature (ds18b20) sensors with raspberry pi?
If I can, what gpio pins should I use and how?
So what pin can i use instead of gpio 4...

Comment: Couple of things from a quick search here: [(1)](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-ds18b20-probes-that-can-attached-to-one-input-port) -- [(2)](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23195/sensor-ds18b20-i2c-weird-response).  I don't think they are direct answers to or duplicates of your question, but they do hopefully have some clues and implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi supports one 1-wire bus (currently, in the future more may be supported).

Each 1-wire bus supports an arbitrary number of 1-wire sensors so you can add as many DS18B20 as you want.

By default the 1-wire bus is connected to GPIO 4 (pin 7).

You enable the 1-wire bus by adding the following line to `/boot/config.txt`.

`dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4`

If you want to use an alternate GPIO change 4 to the (Broadcom numbered) GPIO you want to use.

There are several examples of reading the DS18B20 if you use the site search engine.

Comment: Thank you! I had a problem with it so it's why I've asked, but now everything is okey